# Spring boot Transaction integrity across multiple pods in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a spring boot application which is supposed to run in kubernetes cluster. so, my doubt is , how can i maintain transaction integrity across multiple pods in kubernetes cluster ?

i am expecting the transaction integrity across pods

Comment: What do you mean by `transaction integrity`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.